# Converting European to American Number format in R

Tags: r, csv, import

I'm trying to work with a file that is saved as a .csv file but is actually ; deliminated. The decimal points are commas. 
Example of a row:

> SAA1;6,022367813;10,9403136;5,807354922;3,169925001;3,807354922;8,636624621;5,247927513;5,459431619;9,09011242;4,247927513;4,087462841;5,247927513;4,584962501;11,17492568;4,754887502;6,857980995;7,409390936;7,499845887;8,224001674;10,19967234;9,638435914;4,700439718;6,14974712;2,807354922;0;7,348728154;4,700439718;6,820178962;4,700439718;6,044394119;1,584962501;6,044394119;6,375039431;3,807354922;9,087462841;8,74819285;5,614709844;8,330916878;6,62935662;5,169925001;6,442943496;2,321928095;8,312882955;9,240791332;2,807354922;9,06608919;6,539158811;5,64385619;4,584962501;6,700439718;6,108524457;7,539158811;6,658211483;8,982993575;5,285402219;8,744833837

I need to read this data into R and then work with it as numbers where decimal points are "."

Here's what I've tried:

```
read.csv2("filename.csv", row.names=1, sep=";",dec=",")
```

This almost worked. Most of the numbers were correctly read in with periods. However all the numbers in certain columns remained separated by commas. I tried to fix this with:

```
temp<-sub(",", ".", data)
```

However, this did not quite work. It truncated several of the numbers and completely corrupted other ones. I have no idea why.

I've also tried opening the file in Sublime text. I found and replaced all commas with periods. This again worked for the majority of the data, but several numbers again became corrupted.

I've also tried reading in the file without changing the comma delimited nature, writing it period deliminated and then reading it in again.

```
temp<-read.csv2("filename.csv", row.names=1, sep=";")
write.csv2(temp, "filename_edited", sep = ";", dec=".", row.names = TRUE, col.names = TRUE)
temp2 <- read.csv2("filename_edited", sep=";", row.names=1)
```

This also didn't work. (I'm not surprised, I was getting desperate.)

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: I am having no issue reading in your sample file with either of these: read.csv2("filename.csv", header = F, sep = ";", dec = ",") or library(readr);    read_csv2("filename.csv", col_names = F)
And the output is properly converted.

If this does not work for you, I think that you need to share more of the data so that your problem can be reproduced.

Comment: you could also try reading the file with `readr` package: `library(readr); read_csv2("filename.csv")`, see if that handles the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A common issue is related to trailing white space before or after the numbers (e.g. " 342,5", instead of "342,5"). Have you tried using the `strip.white=TRUE` parameter, like:

```
read.csv2("filename.csv", row.names=1, sep=";", strip.white=TRUE)
```

If you otherwise pre-process the data, `trimws()` may also be useful in this context.